# Why would print_r ($row); only be returning a number 1?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to learn PHP5 and am having a couple of problems with it.  I am working with prepared statements and am trying to run the following code:

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/config.php';

$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or 
die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');

$query = "SELECT * FROM user_table";

    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->execute();

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            print_r ($row);
        }

    }

?>
```

I have 2 rows it should return each containing an id, login_name, login_password and a login_level.

When the statement runs it only prints the following:

11

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) method returns `TRUE`, `FALSE`, or `NULL` depending on whether it succeeded in fetching the data. It doesn't return the data in an array. Instead it places the results in variables bound by the [bind_result()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) method.

Answer (score 1):

It returns 1 because 1 is TRUE in PHP.

What you should do is bind a variable with the `[bind_result][1]` method and then do:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf ("%s\n", $variable);
}
```

A great example is on the [bind result documentation page.](http://is.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to get that this way you first need to bind the result variables like this:

```
$stmt->execute();

// bind the result variables in order 
$stmt->bind_result($id, $login_name, $login_password, $login_level);

// then get results
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    var_dump($id, $login_name, $login_password, $login_level);
}
```